# If $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $M \subseteq N$, $G/N$ cyclic and $|N/M|=2$ prove that $G/M$ is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

If $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $M \subseteq N$, $G/N$ cyclic and $|N/M|=2$ prove that $G/M$ is Abelian.

If $M$ is a subgroup of $N$, keeping in mind that $[N:M]=2$, we can get that $M \triangleleft N$. Also from Third isomorphism theorem we have: $$(G/M)/(N/M) \cong G/N$$

$G/N$ is cyclic, so $(G/M)/(N/M)$ has to be also cyclic. $G/M$ has elements of form $gM$ and $(G/M)/(N/M)$ has elements of form $gM(N/M)$ and because $N/M = \{M, nM \}$,  $gM(N/M) = \{gM, gnM \}$. This is cyclic, so $n = g^k$. If $n = g^k$ then is also $m = g^l$. I am not sure what to do with this, can someone please help me?

Comment: I would just set $G' = G/M$ and $N' = N/M$ to begin with, and work directly with $G'$ and $M'$, forgetting that they are quotient groups. It should make all the notation an order of magnitude easier to both read and write, as there is no need to deal with borderline illegible stuff like $(G/M)/(N/M)$. The third isomorphism theorem is such a blessing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the two following results, showing your question is part of general facts of group theory.

**Lemma 1** If $N \unlhd G$ and $|N|=2$, then $N \subseteq Z(G)$

**Proof** If $N=\{1,n\}$ ($n \neq 1$) and $g \in G$ arbitrary, then, since $N$ is normal, $g^{-1}ng \in N$. But since $n \neq 1$, $g^{-1}ng \neq 1$, so $g^{-1}ng=n$, that is $ng=gn$, whence $n$ is central. $\square$

**Lemma 2** Let $A \subseteq Z(G)$ with $G/A$ being cyclic. Then $G$ is abelian.

**Proof** Write $G/A=\langle \overline{g} \rangle$, where $\overline{g}$ denotes the coset $gA$. If $x,y \in G$, then $\overline{x}=\overline{g}^i$ for some integer $i$, so, $x=g^ia$, for some $a \in A$. Similarly, $y=g^jb$ for some integer $j$ and $b \in A$. Using that $A$ is central we now see, $xy=g^iag^jb=g^{i+j}ab=g^jg^iba=g^jbg^ia=yx.$ $\square$

Back to the post: we see that $N/M \unlhd G/M$ and $|N/M|=2$. By Lemma 1 we get $N/M \subseteq Z(G/M)$. But $(G/M)/(N/M) \cong G/N$ is cyclic, so by Lemma 2, $G/M$ is abelian. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Following Arthur's suggestion in the comments above, denote $G/M$ by $G'$ and $N/M$ as $N'$. As you've noted, $G'/N'$ is cyclic, being isomorphic to $G/N$.

Therefore, it suffices to check that every element of $N'$ commutes with every element of $G'$. Since $N'$ is normal in $G'$, for $g' \in G'$, $n_1', n_2' \in N'$, $g'n_1' = n_2'g'$. Since $N'$ is of order $2$, either $n_2' = 1$ or $n_2' = n_1'$. Suppose the former. Then $g'n_1' = g'$, hence $n_1' = 1 = n_2'$. Thus, $n_1' = n_2'$ and the elements of $N'$ commute with every element of $G'$. So $G'$ is abelian.

Comment: Why is it enough to check that every element of N' commutes with every element of G'?

Comment: @smth: See the end of Keith Conrad's answer above for the details.

Answer (score 1):

As in the other answer, we work modulo $M$ throughout to minimize the need for quotient groups, but I am also going to get rid of the prime notion (') in the other answer since that is a bit annoying to see everywhere. So rewriting $G/M$ as $G$ and $N/M$ as $N$, we are working with a group $G$ that has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $2$ such that $G/N$ is cyclic and we want to show $G$ is abelian.

Since $N$ has order $2$, we can write $N = \{1,n\}$. For $g \in G$, $gNg^{-1} = N$, which says $\{1,gng^{-1}\} = \{1,n\}$, so $gng^{-1} = n$. Thus $gn = ng$, so everything in $G$ commutes with $n$. Since $G/N$ is cyclic, let $x \in G$ represent a generator of $G/N$, so $G/N = \{x^kN : k \in \mathbf Z\}$. Thus $G = \{x^k, x^kn : k \in \mathbf Z\}$, so $G$ is generated by $x$ and $n$, which commute. Hence $G$ is abelian.